# Confirm form resubmission on child action persisting

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

First of all, i want to assure that i have already read dozens of posts on SO resembling it, but none of them represents my exact issue and none of answers were able to help me get rid of "Confirm form re-submission".

Using ASP.NET mvc5, i have created a comment table, class, views(not partial) and actions for list and create.

When a user adds comment, it is successfully added to the table, but when he refreshes the page even without entering anything in the comment box, Confirm form re-submission appears. If he click continue, same comment is added to database again, which i don't want.

On webpages which comment functionality is to be added, my code is

```
@Html.Action("Create", "Comment");
```

My action methods to add comment are

```
public actionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public actionResult Create(Comments comments)
{
    //create logic
   return View("Create") // Also tried giving no argument.
}
```

Most of solutions on places recommend redirect to action to a get method, but it  gives yellow page error that child action can't perform redirect. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: You *do* need to redirect instead of returning a view. The problem is that your `@Html.Action("Create", "Comment")` is calling the wrong method.

Comment: @haim770 to add a comment from user, what else can i call instead of create?

Comment: The exact flow is still unclear in your question. Which is the main (root) action and which is the child action that you intend to invoke using `@Html.Action`?

Comment: @haim770 Say that there is a view product.cshtml. I want users be able to add a comment at the end of the view, so i added the above line. It shows create view for comment table properly and comment is added to DB successfully. So here Create action of comment controller is the child action and the parent action will be the one which renders product.cshtml

Comment: Have you use any attribute on action methods?

Comment: No @arpandesai haven't used

Answer (score 1):

On the post just use ,

```
return RedirectToAction("Create"); //instead of return view
```

This will redirect to the same view after post and also prevents confirm form re-submission on refresh

Comment: Sorry, but as i have already specified, it gives yellow page error that Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions

Comment: is create a partial view ?

Comment: No, create is not a partial view

Comment: try this , [ActionFilters.RequireHttps(RequireSecure = true)] in your 
  in ControllerBase class, initially it will be false

Comment: then try to redirect

Comment: Giving compile error = type or namespace ActionFilters doesn't exist. I have already added system.web.mvc to references

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106429/discussion-between-rachit-gupta-and-redevi).